# Flaky test failures in Minitest due to UTC time mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

Can anyone shed any light on what is causing this test to randomly fail?

There's obviously a mismatch between the time formats but I don't understand why it's happening randomly.

Our test:-

```
  # MeetingControllerTest

  test 'returns correctly when page param is not set' do    
    30.times do |i|
      Meeting.create!(
        start_date: @meeting.start_date + (i + 1).days,
        end_date: @meeting.end_date + (i + 1).days,
        user: @meeting.user,
        calendar_event_id: @meeting.calendar_event_id
      )
    end

    get meetings_url,
        params: {
          summary: 'meeting',
          per_page: 5,
          page: nil
        },
        headers: { 'Authorization' => @authorization }
    assert_response :success
    response_body = JSON.parse(response.body)
    meetings = response_body['meetings']

    assert_equal((@meeting.start_date + 4.days).strftime('%FT%T.%LZ'), meetings.last['start_date'])
  end
```

The assertion failure is:-

```
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-"2021-09-06T16:19:14.000Z"
+"2021-09-06T16:19:14.000+01:00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [assert_in_delta](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#available-assertions). Replace this:

```
assert_equal((@meeting.start_date + 4.days).strftime('%FT%T.%LZ'), meetings.last['start_date'])
```

To this:

```
assert_in_delta((@meeting.start_date + 4.days).strftime('%FT%T.%LZ'), meetings.last['start_date'], 1.second)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's almost impossible to help debugging this without the rest of the code (what is `@meeting`, the controller action).

It would be also interesting if this test is flaky running on its own or just when running as part of the whole test suite. This wold indicate if there might be a leaky state.

My best guess is either non consistent sorting or something is changing your timezone (leaky state).

Here is a good article what can cause flaky tests and how to debug and fix them.

https://sourcediving.com/flaky-tests-are-not-random-failures-363fbddc1774
https://sourcediving.com/a-methodological-approach-to-fixing-flaky-tests-92a39162b769